# How to create a Search all columns in SuiteScript 2.0 version

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

How I can create select * from in suitescript?

I need all columns from the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the 'N/query'

```
        require(['N/query'], function(query) {
var sql =     "SELECT * from  TRANSACTION WHERE TRANSACTION_ID=XXXX;

    var resultIterator = query.runSuiteQLPaged({
    query: sql,
    pageSize: 10
    }).iterator();

    resultIterator.each(function(page) {
    var pageIterator = page.value.data.iterator();
    pageIterator.each(function(row) {
    log.debug('ID: ' + row.value.getValue(0) + ', Context: ' + row.value.getValue(1));
    return true;
    });
    return true;
    });
    });
```

Before you do that   run the query in  ODBC because some columns cannot been loaded (pdf,xml data)